# EL integer converter in forEach

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, mojarra

I am unable to populate a select with integers. It seems that String values are populated for numbers from 0 to 15. However 16 is OK.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{myBean.myIntegerValue}" >
    <c:forEach begin="0" end="15" var="e">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{e}" itemValue="#{e}"/>
    </c:forEach>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="16" itemLabel="16" />

    <f:convertNumber integerOnly="true" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

(if i select a value between 0-15 I get a validation error:  Value is not valid)

Any Ideas? 
Mojarra 2.2.6, glassfish 4.0.1

Thanks

Comment: 16 doesn't work neither. If I select 16 I get a BigDecimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing this tag: `<f:convertNumber integerOnly="true" />` should solve the problem.